# KendoUI Treeview shows twisty even when has no children

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendoui treeview displaying some data obtained from a json datasource. The treeview is working with the exception that it displays the twisty for child items even when there are no child items.

I believe this is related to my json string but at this point I don't believe I can change it.

Here is the json string:

```
[{"Title":"Shared Documents","spriteCssClass":"folder","LastModified":"1/15/2013 10:42:20 AM","Items":[{"Title":"Folder 1","spriteCssClass":"folder","LastModified":"1/15/2013 10:42:20 AM","Items":[{"Title":"Subfolder 1","spriteCssClass":"folder","LastModified":"1/15/2013 10:41:52 AM","Items":[]},{"Title":"Test Tax Document.docx","spriteCssClass":"docx","LastModified":"1/15/2013 10:42:20 AM","Items":[]}]}]}]
```

I believe the problem is that the Items[] still exist even if there are no items.

Here is the code for my treeview...

```
var treeDS = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: json,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    children: "Items"
                }
            }
        });

var treeview = $("#CCA_DocLibTreeViewer_Tree").kendoTreeView({
            template: "#= item.Title # - #= item.LastModified # <a href='\\#'>View</a>",
            dataSource: treeDS,
            dataTextField: ["Title", "Title"]
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Any thoughts on what I can do about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, the question is that if it has `Items` no matter the `length` it assumes that has children.

The solution is either do not generate those empty `Items` or define `treeDS` as:

```
var treeDS = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data  : json,
    schema: {
        model: {
            children   : "Items",
            hasChildren: function (node) {
                return (node.Items && node.Items.length > 0);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can see that I have defined a `hasChildren` function that verifies that `node.Items` exists and its `length` is actually greater than `0`.

You might see it running in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9e6TX/)